# How Can I show negative and positive numbers as a size and colour on Python Plotly map graph

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I just created a map graph with Plotly that shows sales difference of years so result has negative and positive numbers.

I want to show two different colours that represent positive and negative numbers and size of circle represent volume of sales difference. 
I want to do, even negative numbers so small circle is big that show volume but colour different than positive colour.

My code shows only biggest and lowest number difference with colour and negative numbers are too small.

How can I show sales difference on the graph with 2 different colour with size of circle?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *


mapbox_access_token = '**Mapbox API**'

data = Data([
    Scattermapbox(
        lat=part1_loc['Latitude'],
        lon=part1_loc['Longitude'],
        text =  part1_loc['diff2018'], 
        mode='markers',
        marker=Marker(
            showscale=True,
                cmax=39000,
                cmin=-27000,
            size= part1_loc['diff2018'],
            color =part1_loc['diff2018'],
            #color ='rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            colorscale= 'Portland',
            opacity=0.6,
            symbol = 'circle',

        ),

    )
])
layout = Layout(
    autosize=True,
    hovermode='closest',
    width=1450,
        margin=go.Margin(
        l=10,
        r=100,
        b=10,
        t=10
        ),
    height=650,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,#
        center=dict(
            lat=-37,
            lon=175
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=8.9,
        style='light',


    ),
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='Sales_diff')
```

Here you are my result graph;

[image]

Also I found an example to use for two variables in Plotly [here is the link](https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/#nuclear-waste-sites-on-campuses)
but I do not know how I can seperate negative and positive numbers as different variables in one data.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

in my experience I used the absolute value to increase the size of negative numbers.

In my case, the dataset was pretty balanced and the more the value was far from zero and the more important it was to be visualized. So, I decided to colour the circles based on their values (as you did) and set their size in order to define their importance.

In your case you'd just need to set the parameter size as follows:

```
size= part1_loc['diff2018'].abs()
```

Please, pay attention that this solution was optimal for my purposes which did not give much importance to the values close to zero. On the contrary, if you don't want them to be too small, you need to set a minimal size (maybe with a list comprehension?).